# Php file works and is displaying in browser but i always get "404 error php file not avaliable"

Tags: php, windows, nginx, http-status-code-404

Previously my server was running fine until one day my server's software suddenly crashed and now I always get this error in console even with the right configuration. I don't know why my server crashed, but when it crashed the website stopped loading until i shut it down and slightly changed the configuration file. The php file is avaliable and it's executing properly and displaying fine on the browser but in the browser's console it always output this error.

> GET http://localhost/index.php 404 (Not Found)

and when i try to do something that involves loading external php script i would get the same error

I'm using Windows 10 with nginx 1.21.6 and php 8.1.5. I've tried different nginx and php version, using different browsers, checking that the configuration file is right but i still have the same issue. I've also tried using postman to do a get request and it worked with postman. I've tried hosting my website on localhost and on my actual domain but i get the same error. I don't think the error is in the php file itself because i've already tried a php file which have only one code `phpinfo();` that doesn't have any complicated stuff but it still didn't work.

My Nginx Configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }



# HTTPS server
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  localhost;

        ssl_certificate      fullchain2.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  privkey2.pem;

        ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }

}
```

My PHP Configuration:

```
doc_root = "c:\nginx-1.21.6\html"
extension_dir = "c:\php-8.1.5\ext"

extension=bz2
extension=curl
extension=ffi
extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gettext
extension=mbstring
extension=exif 
extension=mysqli
extension=openssl
extension=pdo_mysql
```

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know if you have any answers.

Update: I've included error.log and access.log

error.log

```
2022/04/24 12:08:18 [emerg] 8960#5044: unknown log format "main" in C:\nginx-1.20.2/conf/nginx.conf:40
2022/04/24 12:08:23 [emerg] 10396#10740: unknown log format "main" in C:\nginx-1.20.2/conf/nginx.conf:40
2022/04/24 12:08:34 [emerg] 2876#3520: unknown log format "main" in C:\nginx-1.20.2/conf/nginx.conf:40
2022/04/24 12:09:00 [emerg] 752#7000: unknown log format "main" in C:\nginx-1.20.2/conf/nginx.conf:24
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: using the "select" event method
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: using the "select" event method
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: nginx/1.20.2
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: nginx/1.20.2
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [info] 5476#2288: OS: 260200 build:9200, "", suite:300, type:1
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: start worker processes
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: start worker processes
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: start worker process 11196
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 5476#2288: start worker process 11196
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: nginx/1.20.2
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: nginx/1.20.2
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [info] 11196#3576: OS: 260200 build:9200, "", suite:300, type:1
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: create thread 6528
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: create thread 6528
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: create thread 7516
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: create thread 7516
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: create thread 9144
2022/04/24 12:09:21 [notice] 11196#3576: create thread 9144
2022/04/24 12:09:31 [info] 11196#6528: *1 client 127.0.0.1 closed keepalive connection
2022/04/24 12:09:31 [info] 11196#6528: *3 client closed connection while waiting for request, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:80
```

access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2022:12:02:56 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 88053 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2022:12:02:59 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 88053 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Mobile Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [24/Apr/2022:12:09:25 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 88053 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.127 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

**UPDATE 2: I FINALLY FIXED THE PROBLEM USING APACHE**

Comment: what in is your `access.log` and `error.log`?

Comment: I've included it in the post. The problem is only happeneing in php files.

Comment: do you have problem on `80` served port or `443` one? Also, what's your absolute `root` path?

Comment: The error is still avaliable regardless of ports. My root path in windows is C:\nginx-1.20.2\html

Comment: is `php-fpm` is **actually** running on `127.0.0.1:9000` host and port?